# Why google recaptcha doesn't let me click on checkbox in chrome developer tools of mobile version

Tags: javascript, css, recaptcha

I am trying to implement google captcha in my project but I am facing two problems...

1) It doesn't let me click on checkbox when I open mobile versions using chrome developer tools..but it let me click on checkbox when I tried to click from actual mobile.

2) For the image selection(verify images), I am not able to customize the css, by default in my project it comes on very right of the screen which creates unnecessary horizontal bar.

below is the sample of google recaptcha link

[recartcha link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WPZGRW)

Using chrome developer tools I got below id and i tried to customize but no luck'

```
#rc-imageselect{
  background-color:green !important;
  color:red !important;
}
```